# What is the output of a fingerprint scanner? Is there any deterministic identifying information?

Tags: algorithm, output, hardware, fingerprint, biometrics

I am planning on generating a set of public/private keys from a deterministic identifying piece of information from a person and was planning on using fingerprints.

My question, therefore, is: what is the output of a fingerprint scanner? Is there any deterministic output I could use, or is it always going to be a matter of "confidence level"? i.e. Do I always get a "number" which, if matched exactly to the database, will allow access, or do I rather get a number which, if "close enough" to the stored value on the database, allows access, based on a high degree of confidence, rather than an exact match?

I am quite sure the second option is the answer but just wanted to double-check. Is there any way to get some sort of deterministic output? My hope was to re-generate keys every time rather than actually storing fingerprint data. That way a wrong fingerprint would simply generate a new and useless key.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you selected a fingerprint scanner and perused its datasheet/specifications yet? If so, were there any relevant portions that might be beneficial to add to the question?

Comment: Andrey, unfortunately I have not used a fingerprint scanner yet nor selected one to use for that matter. Wanted to confirm the general viability of the idea before proceeding any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against it for several reasons.

- The fingerprints are not entirely deterministic. As suggested in @ImSimplyAnna answer, you might 'round' the results in order to have more chances to obtain a deterministic result. But that would significantly reduce the number of possible/plausible fingerprints, and thus not meet the search space size requirement for a cryptographic algorithm. On top of it, I suspect the entropy of such result to be somehow low, compared to the requirements of modern algorithm which are always based on high quality random numbers.
- Fingerprints are not secret, we expose them to everyone all the time, and they can be revealed to an attacker at any time, and stored in a picture using a simple camera. A key must be a secret, and the only place we know we can store secrets without exposing them is our brain (which is why we use passwords).
- An important feature for cryptographic keys is the possibility to generate new one if there is a reason to believe the current ones might be compromised. This is not possible with fingerprints.

That is why I would advise against it. Globally, I discourage anyone (myself included) to write his/her own cryptographic algorithm, because it is so easy to screw them up. It might be the easiest thing to screw up, out of all the things you could write, because attacker are *so vicicous*!
The only good approach, if you're not a skilled specialist, is to use libraries that are used all around, because they've been written by experts on the matter, and they've been subject to many attacks and attempts to break them, so the ones still standing will offer much better levels of protection that anything a non specialist could write (or basically anything a single human could write).
You can also have a look [at this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/58897/writing-your-own-encryption-algorithm), on the crypto stack exchange. They also discourage the OP in using anything else than a battle hardened algorithm, or protocol.

Edit:

> I am planning on generating a set of public/private keys from a
>   deterministic identifying piece of information

Actually, It did not strike me at first (it should have), but keys MUST NOT be generated from anything which is not random. NEVER.
You have to generate them randomly. If you don't, you already give more information to the attacker than he/she wants. Being a programmer does not make you a cryptographer. Your user's informations are at stake, do not take any chance (and if you're not a cryptographer, you actually don't stand any).

Comment: Yeah so the plan was not to make my own algorithm, but rather use a library with an input consisting of various values, one of which would be the fingerprint. But you've given me enough reason to believe that's perhaps not the best approach.

Comment: I've just found the answer to the very question you were asking on [the crypto stack exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/58716/how-is-biometric-data-used-to-generate-encryption-keys). I'm no cryptographer, but I had some 'gut feeling' that fingerprints were not really safe. And it confirms it: there is not enough entropy (~40 bits) in fingerprints to generate a key, and the fact that fingeprints are not secret is also an issue.

Comment: Some companies have been trying to present it as a trendy and safe system (some computers/smartphones even come with fingerprints readers, which gives users a false sense of protection), but it has always been heavily decried in the crypto community.

Answer (score 1):

A fingerprint scanner looks for features where the lines on the fingerprint either split or end. It then calculates the distances and angles between such features in an attempt to find a match.

Here's some more reading on the subject: 
https://www.explainthatstuff.com/fingerprintscanners.html 
in the section "How fingerprints are stored and compared".
The source is the best explanation I can find, but looking around some more it seems that all fingerprint scanners use some variety of that algorithm to generate data that can be matched.

Storing raw fingerprints would not only take up way more space on a database but also be a pretty significant security risk if that information was ever leaked, so it's not really done unless absolutely necessary.

Judging by that algorithm, I would assume that there is always some "confidence level". The angles and distances will never be 100% equal between scans, so there has to be some leeway to make sure a match is still found even if the finger is pressed against the scanner a bit harder or the finger is at a slightly different angle.

Based on this, I'd assume that generating a key pair based on a fingerprint would be possible, if you can figure out a way to make similar scans result in the same information. Simply rounding the angles and distances may work, but may introduce cases where two different people generate the same key pairs, or cases where different scans of the same fingerprint have a high chance of generating several different keys.